# Load script order in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I need to load a jquery script when loading my Joomla 2.5 component; in my view i added:

```
function display($tpl = null)
{
// Display the template
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScript("components/com_myname/assets/js/script.js","text/javascript",true);
parent::display($tpl);
}
```

but the script is never executed because the script.js is loaded before the jquery.js.
How can I establish the load order of the scripts without hacking joomla core or template files?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to add jquery first to document:

```
$document->addScript('/path/to/jquery/jquery.min.js');
$document->addScript('components/com_myname/assets/js/script.js');
```

to avoid loading multiple jquery instances by multiple extensions, use the following code which is followed by most developers.

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
if(!$app->jquery){
  $document->addScript('/path/to/jquery/jquery.min.js');
  $app->jquery = true;
}
```

And if you cannot control how jquery is loaded, you can use below method.

```
$document->addCustomTag('<script src="'.JURI::root(true).'/components/com_myname/assets/js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
```

custom tags will be loaded after all other scripts loaded.

Comment: $document->addCustomTag(); was the way to go for me.